# EF Core 5 - Multiple navigation properties with same (related) foreign key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I have a table that looks like this. The related ID is the primary id for data that will only ever be present in one of three other tables (represented by Type1, 2 & 3 - eg. Type1 may contain a row for the relatedid, but Type2 and Type3 won't). When I try to include all three entities to check for their presence, ef core generates an inner join against all three navigation properties, which returns null for every navigation property because only one of the tables contains data for the related id, while the others don't, and therefore an inner join against all three returns no results. The only way of returning one property as set to the appropriate table is if the join is a left join, which the foreign key attribute/fluent model does not specify.

Obviously, in SQL the related ID cannot be a true foreign key, but I'm using the attribute to tag the navigation properties. The primary key of each Type1, 2 & 3 is the RelatedID of this table.

Regardless of whether this is correct database design (using a related ID in this way) - is it possible to force EF core to return these entities using a left/outer join so the query can succeed, or must I not use navigational properties in this context because there's no way to make them query without an inner join? Or is there an alternative attribute I could/should use to imply this relationship? I'd prefer not to require three separate columns with foreign keys for each of the related tables (we don't like having lots of extra columns that would be filled with null values, because only one of the columns would be populated).

```
public class SomeThing
{
    [Key]
    public Guid PrimaryID { get; set; }

    public Guid RelatedID { get; set; }

    // There is only ever data for one of these types
    [ForeignKey("RelatedID")]
    public virtual Type1 Related1{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RelatedID")]
    public virtual Type2 Related2 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RelatedID")]
    public virtual Type3 Related3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In Entity Framework Core, one foreign key property cannot participate in multiple relationships.

Comment: Yes, that does sum up the problem. So my question was, is there a database annotation I *can* use, or am I stuck with manual joins?

Comment: I read the edited post. And I must say, one's narrative doesn't _always_ conveys the message appropriately as they were intended, specifically in developers' community. There's always chances of getting misinterpreted. So, it would be better if you could describe your scenario/requirement in terms of code, and not in English sentences.

Comment: For example,  1) "_related ID can be the primary id in one of three other tables_" - foreign key doesn't get setup dynamically based on your query, so you have to create all three relations. 2) "_Only one of these will ever be present._" - that's a vague description. Do you mean only one of the parent reference will be present in your `LINQ` queries?  3) "_therefore an inner join against all three would return no results_" - but  I checked, and it returns all three in the result. Did you mean to say it _should not_ return any result (like you are expecting it to be)?

Comment: I hope I've been a bit clearer. In my data, only one of the related tables will have a row that matches the related ID at any one time. Because of the inner join being performed across all three tables (two of which would not yield results) to populate the navigation properties, they all return null. I hope that's a bit clearer.
For the moment, I'm having to use separate joins with defaultifempty and then select the properties where the results are not null.